# Symbol on Shiva linga

Tags: vedas, shiva, shiva-lingam

*lThere’s a triangle similar symbol on most of shiva Lingam’s. What does the symbol represent. Can anyone explain please?*

Comment: Can you share a picture for reference? A triangle pointing downwards represent Shakti.

Comment: The BLISS that emanates out of merger of ascending power (Agni ) with the power at Other end in human is called **Soma** in the Veda.  In puranas,  it was described, due to misunderstanding the Vedic concept,  as phallus, the ascending power in yoga .  However, most of the people ignore the 2nd part of the Shiva linga, ie, the Base. That indicates 2nd power.

Comment: The Star of David, a symbol of Judaism as a religion, and of the Jewish people as a whole. And it also thought to be the shield (or at least the emblem on it) of King David. Actually,  it is the Vedic concept of **Soma**, depicted in the form of merger of 2 triangles that are positioned in opposite directions.

Comment: I hv seen either eye or sarpa or both..but didn't observe triangle...can u share picture?